# Histogram of binary image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram

I'm trying to do a vertical histogram of a binary image. I don't want to use MATLAB's functions. How to do it?

I have tried this code but I don't know if it's correct or not:

```
function H = histogram_binary(image)
[m,n] = size(image);
H = zeros(1,256);
for i = 1:m
    for j = 1:n
        H(1,image(i,j)) = H(1,image(i,j))+1;
    end
end
```

The image is:

[image: The picture]

The result:

[image: vertical histogram]

Why can't I see the value of black pixels in the histogram?

Comment: You can visit this link http://ciphervision.com/ for detailed implementation and demo in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
% Read the binary image...
img = imread('66He7.png');

% Count total, white and black pixels...
img_vec = img(:);
total = numel(img_vec);
white = sum(img_vec);
black = total - white;

% Plot the result in the form of an histogram...
bar([black white]);
set(gca(),'XTickLabel',{'Black' 'White'});
set(gca(),'YLim',[0 total]);
```

Output:

[image: BW Histogram]

For what concerns your code, it is not counting black pixels since they have a value of `0` and your loop start from `1`... rewrite it as follows:

```
function H = histogram_binary(img)
    img_vec = img(:);
    H = zeros(1,256);

    for i = 0:255
        H(i+1) = sum(img_vec == i);
    end
end
```

But keep in mind that counting all the byte occurrences on a binary image (that can only contain `0` or `1` values) is kinda pointless and will make your histogram lack readability. On a side note, avoid using `image` as a variable name, since this would override [an existing function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html).

Comment: Belluzo : i wanted the vertical histogram of a binary image so i can next count how many letters are in the picture based on the histogram , is it possible with your method ? and thank you

Comment: i have edited the post you can see the real  binary image , it countains 11 caracteres , i have a project in which i should do a vertical histogram of the binary image , and after that ,i should  implement a method that counts the numbers of caracteres in the picture , can you suggest any solution ?

Comment: I'm sorry but this has nothing to do with the original question... take a look at this https://mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/ocr.html for counting the characters: `img = imread('YcP1o.png'); info = ocr(img); chars = numel(strtrim(info.Text));`

Comment: An alternative to counting letters is doing connected component labeling: `[~,num] = bwlabel(image)`. You might need to invert the image to make the letters white and the background black.

Comment: Ah nice one! Let me try this!

Comment: for the code of histogram yes it works , but for counting characters not really :/

Comment: @Cris Luengo : how?

Comment: For me the OCR works fine. It returns 13 characters... which is correct.

Comment: @dEs12ZER What do you mean with "how?"? Did you try the bit of code I posted?

Comment: I assume that the OP is looking for a vertical projection profile, which I've seen confusingly called a histogram in a couple of papers, for character segmentation. In which case the answer is `H = sum(image, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @[beaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1377097/beaker) in the comments above, vertical histogram in such cases generally refers to a vertical projection. Here is a way to do this :

```
I = imread('YcP1o.png'); % Read input image
I1 = rgb2gray(I); % convert image to grayscale
I2 = im2bw(I1); % convert grayscale to binary
I3 = ~I2; % invert the binary image
I4 = sum(I3,1); % project the inverted binary image vertically
I5 = (I4>1); % ceil the vector 
plot([1:1:size(I,2)],I5); ylim([0 2])
```

You can further check for `0->1` transitions to count the number of characters using `sum(diff(I5)>0)` which gives `13` as answer in this case.